# Nandland Go Board - Diamond Programmer

Tags: fpga, usb-device

I'm trying to program my first FPGA with the [Nandland Go Board](https://nandland.com/the-go-board/) on Windows 11.

I've followed all the instructions in these tutorial videos:

- https://youtu.be/nfB8-8JfVFE
- https://youtu.be/l_eo21vHxw0

But I'm getting stuck at the very last step, when clicking the "Program" button in Diamond Programmer. Here's a screenshot of the error I keep getting:

[image]

I followed the instructions in the error and read the suggested help topic. Still not working.

One thing worth noting is that in the tutorial video, he has the option to choose either FTUSB-1 or FTUSB-0 for his port. On my laptop I'm only getting the option for FTUSB-0. Not sure if that's related.

Comment: please post text, not a screenshot of text ... screenshot text can't be copied and searched

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

"One thing worth noting is that in the tutorial video, he has the option to choose either FTUSB-1 or FTUSB-0 for his port. On my laptop I'm only getting the option for FTUSB-0. Not sure if that's related."

Have you installed a driver for it? [This is the link](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqa2dUZDBpdGw3X21WR1BLYklhM1RHQlBISDBiZ3xBQ3Jtc0ttSXRDSVR3T0U2LW1BMzh5RDZDNTRsUmU3T0Z1UkZoOVo2S0czODJyQ29VVjFXaEJQTzZlWGxlMGp2TUpQTTNldnptM2w2YmZVTDQ3MjY4X3pqaVhjOGVzdkFFcUdqUnRfd3drQlh5ZGd3TE1kc0pvdw&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ftdichip.com%2FDrivers%2FVCP.htm&v=l_eo21vHxw0) that he puts in his "Nandland Go Project 1" Video in the description. Try installing that first. Using the link that he provides in the description for drivers, try finding the one associated with "VCP".

Then try to see if you can select other COM port options in that Diamond Programmer.

Additionally, I use this particular data transferring cable that I use on other electronics (such as an ESP32) that I used for this board.

Hopefully this helps out

"[Amazon Basics USB-A to Micro USB Fast Charging Cable, 480Mbps Transfer Speed with Gold-Plated Plugs, USB 2.0, 3 Foot, Black](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0711PVX6Z)"